# Is it possible to customise the native player HTML5 Video?

Tags: html, mobile, video

Is it possible to overlay content on the native mobile video players while viewing HMTL5 video? I'm guessing the player is on top of the browser so it's impossible. I want to be able to view comments (HTML content) in a similar way that SoundCloud does. Solution must be cross platform (including feature phones) if it exists, which I doubt it does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about all mobile platforms but it is certainly possible in a desktop browser using the video element. after all it is just an HTML element.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gzk6d/2/) Fiddle.

```
<div>
    <video autoplay controls loop>
            <source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/html5iscool.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            HTML5 Video element not supported
        </video>

    <div class="comment">
        Some overlay text
    </div>
</div>
​

.comment
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px:
}

video{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
​
```

Comment: This would certainly work on desktop browsers, but I believe video on the iPhone  would play fullscreen on top of your comment.

Comment: I suspect you are right. Not sure about the iPhone but on my WP7 the text is displayed over the video control but when you press play it takes you out of the browser into a video player so there is no more markup to display.

Comment: Still, the intial page view could show the content over a video poster. That might be enough to meet his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to display video-content inside the browser on a mobile device. Videos are always loaded and displayed in the video-player of the system, therefore it is not possible to overlay other web-content at runtime.

If it would be possible, Youtube and others would decorate their videos with ads, annotations & comments - similar to their desktop sites.